# "Not only my husband but also my son is a doctor"

Tags: grammatical-number

Starting to review grammar. It's a little confusing for me to identify which is the correct one.

> Not only my husband but also my son is a doctor.

Someone said that it must be *doctors* because there are two subjects in the sentence. But someone else believes it must be *a doctor* because it follows *is*.

Comment: Not only is my husband a doctor, but my son is also.

Comment: @Jim It sounds somewhat more natural, but is a bit garden-pathy: Not only is my husband a doctor, he plays squash for Belgium too.

Answer (score 1):

> - *Not only my husband but also my son* ***[is a doctor/are doctors]***.

Your choice for the singular ***"is a doctor"*** is the right choice.

Supposedly in this type of coordination, the number is determined by the second coordinate--*"but also my son"*--and so, the predicative complement would then be "a doctor" because "my son" is singular. Thus:

- *Not only my husband but also my son* ***is a doctor***.

Related info can be found in the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), page 510, "(d) Not only . . . but also".

Comment: This improves upon the answers in the previous thread in that it gives a supporting reference. It doesn't indicate _why_ 'proximity concord' is used here, though.

Comment: You make a good point. :) -- There's also the possibility that punctuation might also be a factor; e.g. *"Not only her parents--but also Mary--were questioned"*, I'd think that "were" is quite reasonable and probably the only acceptable version, imo. (I'd suspect that context might be the overriding factor.) If this was spoken (not written), then the overall status might end up being of questionable grammaticality--because the listener won't "hear" the em-dashes, but merely hear the two pauses which would be what would've been (also) heard with commas. These kinds of topics might be unclear.